# Enter a valid date/time in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Everytime I select date and time, django form throws "Enter a valid date/time" error.

models.py

```
class Quiz(models.Model):
    ....
    Ending_Time = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    ....
```

forms.py

```
class QuizForm(forms.Form):
    ....
    closing_time = forms.DateTimeField(widget=forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'class':'form-control form-control-lg','type':'datetime-local'}))
    ....
```

views.py

```
def createquiz(request):
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = QuizForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            quiz_text = form.cleaned_data['desc']
            closingtime = form.cleaned_data['closing_time']
            newquiz = Quiz(Description=quiz_text, Ending_Time=closingtime)
            newquiz.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('createques'))
    else:
        form = QuizForm()

    return render(request, "quiz/createquiz.html", {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign a `input_formats` for the `DateTimeField` in `forms.py`

change this line:

```py
closing_time = forms.DateTimeField( widget=forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'class':'form-control form-control-lg','type':'datetime-local'}))
```

to:

```py
closing_time = forms.DateTimeField(input_formats = ['%d/%m/%Y'], widget=forms.DateTimeInput(attrs={'class':'form-control form-control-lg','type':'datetime-local'}))
```